# What is the maximum amount of Poke dollars you can hold?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is it possible to get more than 999,999 Poke dollars or is the max still 999,999?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new limit is 9,999,999 pokedollars, which i found out by having too much free time and over using the prize money o-power. The mega stone prices go down because of how famous you are in lumiose i believe, which is increased by your first league victory...i have seen prices for them go down to 150,000...either this is lumiose fame or they used a lvl 3 o-power, im not certain.

Comment: Mega stones' minimum price is 10k based on how stylish you are. Don't believe it has anything to do with beating the elite four, lots of people just seem to assume that's the reason

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly what the limit is, but my wallet has gone above the 1 million mark, so it is definitely possible to purchase them with sufficient grinding.
Also relevant, I came back to the stone salesman after beating the league once, and his price was only 500,000. After purchasing the stone from him, he'll stock the third kanto-starter mega stone.

The price cut might not be related to the league victory, I didn't really check back there between the 4th gym and the end.

Comment: The prive will go down the more "stylish" you are.

Comment: Also his stock changes every day (rotating completely after 3 days) you don't need to buy them for them to rotate